# What libraries do I need to use std::placeholders?

Tags: c++, bind

Currently I am trying to generate combinations and I am using the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class RandIt, class Compare>
bool next_combination(RandIt first, RandIt mid, RandIt last)
{
    std::sort(mid, last, std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::placeholders::_2
                                            , std::placeholders::_1));
    return std::next_permutation(first, last, std::less<int>());
}
```

Using g++ it fails to compile saying:

```
next_combo.cpp: In function ‘bool next_combination(RandIt, RandIt, RandIt)’:
next_combo.cpp:10: error: ‘bind’ is not a member of ‘std’
next_combo.cpp:10: error: ‘std::placeholders’ has not been declared
next_combo.cpp:11: error: ‘std::placeholders’ has not been declared
```

I thought that std::placeholders were declared in functional, but now I'm confused.
Should I just use boost?

Also the rest of the project is using c++0x, so is there a better way to write this using c++0x features?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you have to use c++0x flag with your g++ compiler to get those.  Or boost::bind.

Comment: why don't you use lambdas instead of cumbersome bind? if you use C++0x, it has sense to write   std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int l, int r)->bool
    {
      return l > r;
    }); intead

Comment: @Kirill, perhaps that would be best to put in an answer ;)

Comment: @Kirill: You don't need to specify the return type for a lambda consisting of a single return statement.

Comment: @GMan I know. I do that in order to make it more explicit because i don't know whether the author familiar with this syntax or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why don't you use lambdas instead of cumbersome bind? if you use C++0x, it has sense to write

`std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int l, int r)->bool { return l > r; });`

instead. Note, that you don't need to specify the return type explicitly there. I wrote this way just to make it clearer.

Answer (score 7):

Off course there is a better way. Use std::greater_equal instead of doing the above. Check [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/less/) what else there is in the functional.

Forgot to say - to use placeholder, you need to enable c++0x features.

Comment: Or rather `std::greater` for descending order, or sort with reverse iterators.